# how do i make my C# application using Access Database to run on LAN using one database

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

i have developed my project in c# using access database so i want it to run on LAN while using Access database on one machine, the problem is that how would i achieve this because if i copy the published application and install it on another machine it is unable to locate the database

Comment: One way that comes to mind is to make a server application that will allow networked access to the database. keep in mind that that would be a lot of work.

Comment: Bad idea - MS Access has heaps of problems supporting > 4 or 5 users concurrently, upgrade it to MS SQL Server (express version is free)

Answer (score 0):

Although I would recommend not using access over a network, here are some things to do and consider if you really want to make it work

1. Have a look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29214/ms-access-database-in-a-network) at our sister site for details on how to allow
   multiple users over the network to access an Access DB.
2. Remember that Access has a size limit (currently 2GB), so you might
   want to setup an auto compact option which you can do by reading
   this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/quick-tip-automatically-compact-access-databases/) which offers step by step instructions.
3. Also, there is a limit on the maximum number of user that can
   connect concurrently as mentioned by [Jeremy Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495455/jeremy-thompson), so you
   might want to handle connection pooling. Read the [best practices
   for ADO.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx)